# How to add certain number of seconds to Sys.time()?

Tags: r, rstudio, systemtime

I was able to get current system time in R using Sys.time() as follows

```
> Sys.time()
[1] "2015-07-10 13:03:21 PDT"
```

But how can I add a certain number of seconds, say 5 seconds so the time would look like "2015-07-10 13:03:26 PDT"

Or maybe add 90 seconds, so the time would look like "2015-07-10 13:04:51 PDT"

Comment: Try `Sys.time() + 5`. See `?"+.POSIXt"` for more details.